# how to reboot server when open file limit reached (Too many open files in system)

Tags: ubuntu, reboot

how can I reboot ubuntu server when open files limit is reached?

I can login via ssh, but mostly every command that I tried responds with error:

```
-bash-4.3$ killall node
-bash: start_pipeline: pgrp pipe: Too many open files in system
-bash: /usr/bin/killall: Too many open files in system
-bash-4.3$ shutdown -r now
-bash: start_pipeline: pgrp pipe: Too many open files in system
-bash: /sbin/shutdown: Too many open files in system
-bash-4.3$ reboot
-bash: start_pipeline: pgrp pipe: Too many open files in system
-bash: /sbin/reboot: Too many open files in system
-bash-4.3$ sudo su -
-bash: start_pipeline: pgrp pipe: Too many open files in system
-bash: /usr/bin/sudo: Too many open files in system
-bash-4.3$
```

Comment: Have you considered fixing the application that's leaking file handles or increasing the number of files you can have open? https://superuser.com/questions/1200539/cannot-increase-open-file-limit-past-4096-ubuntu

Comment: Thanks, I know how to fix it. But the problem is how to stop bad process.

Comment: If you can't login as root and kill the process with `kill` or `kill -9` or execute a `shutdown` the only thing that's left is the power button.

Comment: Try `/sbin/init 6`

Answer (score 0):

Solved by brute-force approach.
I found, that i still can exec kill command (not kilall. killall throws error) but can't find bad process (ps throws error).
I prepared script with several thousands kill commands with consecutive process numbers - and I killed problematic process!